# How to change pages URL in PrestaShop

Tags: url-rewriting, prestashop

I'm a new PrestaShop user and a need to know how to modify pages URL.
This is my website URL to change:

`https://bitec31.example.com/content/6-prodotti`

I want to remove "content/" and the page ID (6), in order to have this:

`https://bitec31.example.com/prodotti`

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot for your help